# How to change root directory of J2ME sun emulator?

Tags: java-me, emulation, java-wireless-toolkit

I need to change the default root directory of sun mobile emulator. I know that you can create and delete roots in the appdb/filesysytem directory, but I need the root to be outside that directory lets say at my hard drive C:/root , is it possible? Thanks, hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root folder is a property of Device configuration.
If you are working with the toolkit that ships with Netbeans looks for an ini file in the same directory where you found the appdb directory.

My best guss is **tmp_jwc_properties.ini** is the file you need. I haven't yet tried it though.

## update

I spent some time trying to do this. But with no success so far.

The property we need to change is probably **system.storage_root** .

But the ini file gets over written with original values every time the IDE is restarted.

Found the original source of this temporary file in

```
My-NetBeans-path\mobility\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0\runtimes\cldc-hi-javafx\bin\jwc_properties.ini
```

As far as I could figure out, the IDE loads settings from this file and adds default values for settings that are not specified in this file.

I'm also new to these tool kits. Please leave a response here if you succeed in doing this.